# Insecure Transport: External Link

Tags: angular, http, frontend, external, insecure-connection

I have Front-End build using Angular 5; There are many call for insecure external link(http://) in my app as example
`<div><a href=http://instanbul-js.org/>istanbul</a></div>`

Is there a way to solve security issue relate to call these http://?

Comment: What not calling https instead ?